# What difference between tsquery and phrasequery in Laravel Scout with postgresql driver?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, search, laravel-scout

Please, tell me what difference between tsquery and phrasequery. I asked because when i tested my code with different configuration - was the same result.

I have this configuration for scout with pgsql driver,

[image]

and in search_using parameter we can choose what type of search i want to use. So when I tried tsquery and do that `$results = User::search('Tom Scoat')->get();` it is crashing.

When i change type to phrasequery it just return empty array. And I can't understand how scout with pgsql driver is working in general. Because it does not search when the word is not exactly the same. For example when `$results = User::search('Scoa')->get();` it return empty array.

Comment: Can you include a bit more information? In what ways are you wondering how the two differ? What are the two configurations you tried?

Comment: @HenryWoody I added answer to my question

Comment: Hey Aleks, thanks for updating, however you should make an edit to your question for this rather than posting as answer.

Answer (score 0):

phrasequery requires the queried terms be adjacent to each other, rather than merely present in the same document.

If you want help testing this, you would need to show us your tests.

Comment: I added answer to my question